# Groups in cytoscape.js

Tags: cytoscape-web

I have a graph that contains nodes (groups) composed by inner nodes and when redering the graph, the groups are shown on top of the nodes they contain (I'm using a `presset layout`). In order to avoid that I have tried setting a z-index (so then only the border of the group is visible) for the groups as shown bellow with no luck.

```
style:{
    selectors:{
        '.group':{
            fillColor: '#000000',
            borderColor: '#000000',
            borderWidth: 1,
            shape:'roundrectangle',
            'z-index':-5
            //visibility:'hidden'
        }

    }
}
```

I also tried setting `visibility:'hidden'` but that hides the edges connecting the group as well. Is there any support for groups ? or maybe a way of setting the group `fillColor` as transparent so it doesn't hide its inner nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SVG renderer should accept `transparent` as a valid colour, as far as I can remember.  What you're really looking for sounds like compound node support, which we'll have when the new canvas renderer is done -- by the end of the summer.

Comment: Setting the colour as `transparent` seems to work. Looking forward for the compound node support!